# How to change rendered selected option in select box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have tried many ways to select an option with jquery including `.val("0")` `.attr('selected', 'selected')` and `.attr('selected', 'true')` and the [TexoTela plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/). They all seem to update the html but the browser still shows the last item selected by the user.

Try out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonparallel/GURje/7/)... Select the dropdown value 1 and then click the link.

Is there any way to actually update the displayed value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean change which item is selected?

`$('select').val('0');`

There are other ways, but this is the basic, following your example.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yWU/)

You can read up on the documenation for `.val()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/val), and the snippet:

> checks, or selects, all the radio
>   buttons, checkboxes, and select
>   options that match the set of values.

**EDIT for jQuery Mobile**

For jQuery Mobile you also need to refresh the select as mentioned in the [mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-selects.html):

> If you manipulate a select via
>   JavaScript, you must call the refresh
>   method on it to update the visual
>   styling.

You can do this by:

`$('select').selectmenu("refresh",true);`

Comment: Looks like I had the selector messed up. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Looks like jQuery mobile was showing the old value which was throwing me off. Had to run .selectmenu('refresh', true); on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I updated the answer to include that info, and links to the mobile docs.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the option value to zero.

Set the select not the option val

```
$('select').val('0');
```

and you'll probably want to use an #id instead just a 'select' selector.

Answer (score 0):

Still use your `.val("0")` to set the value, and to update in the browser you have to use one of the following:

```
.trigger("liszt:updated");
```

or

```
.trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Just one will work, depending on how you create your select.

It's gonna be like:

```
$("#Your_select").val('0');
$("#Your_select").trigger("liszt:updated");
```